# How do I change Google script to delete last downloaded txt file saved in Google Drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google script that will find a gmail attachment and download it to a specific google drive folder and I am running a trigger to have this run on the hour... I would like to add to my script that I want to delete the previous download once the new "hourly" download has been completed.

How do I add script to delete the older downloaded txt file once the newer txt file is downloaded?

This is what I have so far in my Google Script

```
function saveNewAttachmentsToDrive() {
  var folderId = "1WJSIl2iuvuPXffq-99Vhs93Gj5MJ2W4z"; // Replace with the ID of the destination folder in Google Drive
  var searchQuery = "to:lacoe_file@erusd.org"; // Replace with the search query to find emails with attachments
  var lastExecutionTime = getLastExecutionDate();
  var threads = GmailApp.search(searchQuery + " after:" + lastExecutionTime);
  var driveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var message = messages[j];
      var attachments = message.getAttachments();
      for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
        var attachment = attachments[k];
        var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
        var fileName = attachment.getName();
        driveFolder.createFile(attachmentBlob).setName(fileName);
      }
    }
  }
  updateLastExecutionDate();
}

function getLastExecutionDate() {
  var properties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  return properties.getProperty("lastExecutionDate") || "2023-09-01";
}

function resetLastExecutionDate() {
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties().deleteProperty("lastExecutionDate");
}

function updateLastExecutionDate() {
  var now = new Date();
  var dateString = now.toISOString().split("T")[0];
  var properties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  properties.setProperty("lastExecutionDate", dateString);
}
```

Comment: How about just keeping the id of  the last downloaded file and delete all of the rest of the files in the folder.

Comment: OK how do I do that?

Comment: Are the most recent downloads always the files with the newest creation dates?

Comment: yes I believe so

Comment: Are they the only files kept in that folder?

Comment: Yes only that folder! thanks again for helping and yes only those files, however there are two attachments that are being downloaded from two separate emails. The files have separate names tho. Will that matter?

Comment: The code I have given you only keeps one of the files.  Are you know saying you wish to keep 2 of the files?

Answer (score 1):

**Keep newest creation date file in a folder**

> Delete the rest

```
function keepNewestCreationDatedFile() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  let files = folder.getFiles();
  let fA = [];
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    fA.push(file);
  }
  fA.sort((a,b) => b.getDateCreated().valueOf() - a.getDateCreated().valueOf()).shift();
  fA.shift();
  fA.forEach(f => Drive.Files.remove(f.getId());
}
```

You will have to enable Drive API

- [Enable/Disable APIs](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Thank you!  I don't know how to enable Drive API or at least it did not prompt me to enable.  How do I do that?  I added the code and it gave me two errors. 1:09:53 PM Error 
ReferenceError: Drive is not defined
updateLastExecutionDate @ saveNewAttachmentsToDrive.gs:46
saveNewAttachmentsToDrive @ saveNewAttachmentsToDrive.gs:22

Comment: Check the references